# Undefined method `keys' for []:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm getting a Undefined method error:

undefined method `keys' for ["71", "74", "340", "75"]:Array

I'm using Gruff with Prawn to insert an image graph, I have the bar graph displaying properly, but the undefined error is occurring on the label call.

Using prawn (0.15.0) and gruff (0.5.1)

**Prawn**

```
def initialize(result)
 super()
 @result = result
 show_graph
end

def show_graph
lint = @result.map {|v| v.lint/227 } 
g = Gruff::Bar.new('540x200')
g.data(:lint, lint, '#00463f')
@result.each_with_index do |v, i|
g.labels = {i => v.variety.variety_name}
end
g.y_axis_label = 'Yield (bales/ha)'
g.marker_font_size = 16
g.marker_count = 5
g.theme = {:marker_color => '#333333', :font_color => '#333333', :background_colors => %w(#ffffff #ffffff)}
g.minimum_value = 0
g.hide_legend = true

g.write("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/chart.png")

image "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/chart.png"
```

end

**Controller**

```
@result = Result.where('trial_id' => params[:trial_id]).order('lint DESC')
```

Comment: This might be the result of an incompatibility of ruby versions with those versions of prawn and gruff.  Are you using an appropriate version of ruby for the versions of both `prawn` and `gruff`?

Comment: Seems like `labels` expects a hash, and you're giving it an array.

Answer (score 0):

`@result.map` returns an array. A Ruby `Hash` indeed works like a mathematical "map", but another name for Ruby's general `.map` method is `.collect`, because that's all it does. Array in, array out.

I don't know what `g.labels` needs, but you can get a hash with `@result.inject({}){|v, h| h.merge v.variety_id => v.variety }`. Change the argument to `.merge` to fit your needs.

Comment: Cheers Philip, It is requiring a hash, but I have a question about it. It needs 'g.labels {0 => '71', 1 => '74} etc. whats the best method of looping through the number in this scenario? e.g. (1..10).

Comment: And the numbers have to be in order? (Deep breath) `@result.each_with_index.inject({}){|(v, i), h| h.merge i => v.variety_id.to_s }`. Someone check my math on the `(v, i)` part; maybe you can't break the two values out like that. `|q, h|` will definitely return `q[0] == v and q[1] == i`.

Comment: Thanks Phlip, think were in the right direction, but just falling short still. getting an 'undefined method `variety' for {}:Hash'

Comment: I have updated the code above. This work partially as it only lists the last variety for each graph. For example, if the graph had 4 varieties, its only lists the last name.